# Cut off data in pdf table

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, datagridview, itext

I'm trying to cut off the time portion of my data in a PDF printout. The table it prints is from a datagridview table and is the first column called **Date** (`column[0]`). Since removing the time out of the data has proven to be such a pain, I wondered if there was a way to just cut the data that doesn't fit the column. I tried a fixed width and no text wrap but it still wraps the time underneath it. Below is the current code.

```
    private void run_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        SaveFileDialog svg = new SaveFileDialog();
        svg.Filter = "PDF File|*.pdf";
        svg.ShowDialog();

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(svg.FileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
            doc.Open();

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() +"\n\n");
            doc.Add(paragraph);

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(CK_QA_DataDataGridView.Columns.Count);
            table.DefaultCell.Padding = 5;

            table.WidthPercentage = 95;
            table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;
            //Adding Header row

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in CK_QA_DataDataGridView.Columns)
            {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
                cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }
            //Adding DataRow
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in CK_QA_DataDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    table.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            //Add Table
            doc.Add(table);

            doc.Close();
            stream.Close();
```

Comment: To clarify, the date would be displayed, but the time would be too far right of the column to show up.

Comment: Can you explain what problems you encountered when you tried to represent a `Date` object as a string? This seems like something that could easily be fixed instead of just visually just hoping it will be cut off.

Comment: The date column in datagridview displayed a date but for some reason when it is put in the pdf it showed up as a date with the time attached. I suppose I could take the whole date column and extract only the date using a space delimiter. But then I think it would have to be a list.

Comment: You aren't using the displayed value of your DGV in any way, actually, you're just calling `ToString()` on the contents. If you ever happen to have a `null` value you'll actually get an NRE by doing this, bte. However, to get the date you just need to `if/then` or `switch/case` on the column and use a different `ToString()` then the default.

Comment: Even if I'm calling `ToString()` I don't see why it displays only the date in datagridview and displays time and date in my pdf report, as well as my excel export. My database column is Date only. I'll work on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "drop" content that doesn't fit, you could define a `FixedHeight` as done in the [`CellHeights.cs`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter04/CellHeights.cs) example.

In that example, we have the text `"Dr. iText or:\nHow I Learned to Stop Worrying\nand Love PDF."` that we add several times. As this text takes multiple lines, the height of the cell adapts by default. However, in one case, we define a fixed height like this:

```
cell.FixedHeight = 72f;
```

In that case, the text is cut off, see row 4 of [cell_heights.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter04/cell_heights.pdf) for an example.

In the code snippet above, `72f` is a size in user units. One user unit by default corresponds with a point (although they are not exactly the same).

Other options would be to provide a shorter `string` (but I believe that's already what you do when you use `ToShortDateString()`), or you can reduce the font size of your `Paragraph`.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks Bruno!